# Weighted categorical cross-entropy loss

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have 3 classes: A, B and C, and I want to assign different weights to them when computing my loss. I.e. At a later stage when I am making decisions using the model and some probability threshold, taking action on false positives in class A and B are harmful, while that is not the case for class C. Is there any way to modify the loss function to assign some form of weighting scheme to train with this objective in mind?